# How to load test generic handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler, load-testing

I have generic handler that serves dynamic data and I want to make sure that it delivers all  requests to the users(I can see it stalls or sometimes doesn't return when I load it too much manually by putting too much img tags calling it on same page).

Im little confused on how to do this in VS since I don't call it directly, handler gets called through image tags.

What values should I be looking at in counters and how can I evalute how many request can it take at the same time before something goes wrong or reaches max values that shared host providers tolerate(How much is that avg. memory and cpu wise)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drawing the picture happens on the client side, you're not going to avoid it. For all intents and purposes, the handler actually becomes the image. When your displaying page calls the handler, the handler uses the query string to form the reference then generate the image whether it comes from a database or a flat file. So for the most part, all you're generating are references (text). If your page calls the handler a thousand times, the only thing you're going to be waiting on is the images to load.

If your images are stored as a binary in a database, there might be some performance loss. If they are stored in flat files in a directory, then there wont be as all you're doing is generating references. So like pankaj said, if you're not closing your connection and you're hitting the database a thousand times, I could see it getting progressive slower. Other than that... I would guess you have a problem elsewhere. Where are your images stored?